# OpenCL do I need to free host pointer

Tags: c, opencl

If I create an OpenCL buffer with the option CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR and then call clReleaseMemObject on the buffer after using it do I still need to call free on the memory I dynamically allocated.  Also if a kernel write to the buffer will it sync with the host pointer after I call clReleaseMemObject so I can read the result?

Comment: I would have dynamically allocated it since I am giving opencl a pointer to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must free the memory itself.

Think about it - how would OpenCL know the right way to free the memory for you? Maybe it came from `malloc`, or maybe it came from `alloca`, or maybe it came from `VirtualAlloc` (on Windows) or `sbrk` (on Linux), or maybe it's a global variable, or maybe it's a memory-mapped file, or maybe it's a string literal. Perhaps you can think of even more.

OpenCL doesn't know which of those are true, and even if it did, it doesn't even know that you *want* the memory freed. (Unmap that file just because you've finished using OpenCL on it? Maybe you want to run some non-OpenCL code on the same data!)